C# ASP.NET GridView - Row_Updating issues trying to get values from cells in the Gridview with NullReferenceException
There are 2 parts to my question. Please bear with me... just learning this stuff.
I have a GridView that allows editing, which will update a database table. Issue #1 is that I cannot seem to get the values from the GridView in my code behind. I keep getting an error. I've tried it several different ways and I'm at a total roadblock.
Here is the ASP.NET markup:
<asp:GridView ID="ItemView" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" 
     HorizontalAlign="Center"
     PageSize="10" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#6f263d" 
     HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CellPadding="7" CellSpacing="0" 
     DataKeyNames="orderItemId" AllowSorting="True" 
     AlternatingRowStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" 
     AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#6f263d"  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="fancylink" 
     Font-Size="Small" RowStyle-BackColor="#63666A" 
     RowStyle-BorderStyle="None" RowStyle-ForeColor="White" 
     SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#D3D0C8" SelectedRowStyle-ForeColor="Black" 
     Width="100%" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ItemView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" PagerStyle-CssClass="fancylink" 
     PagerStyle-BackColor="#6f263d" PagerStyle-ForeColor="White" 
     PagerSettings-FirstPageText="First Page&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"  
     PagerSettings-Mode="NextPrevious" PagerSettings-NextPageText="Next Page" 
     PagerSettings-LastPageText="End" PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="Previous Page" 
     PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-Width="20%" 
     OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" 
     OnRowDataBound="ItemView_RowDataBound" 
     OnRowEditing="ItemView_EditRow" 
     OnRowUpdating ="ItemView_OnRowUpdating" 
     BorderStyle="None" 
     OnRowCancelingEdit ="ItemView_RowCancelingEdit" 
     OnRowDeleting="ItemView_DeleteRow" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanging="ItemView_OnSelectedIndexChanging" 
     AutoGenerateSelectButton="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_itemId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("orderItemId") %>' ReadOnly="True"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 400px;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Select" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("item") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("item") %>' CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PO Num">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_poNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("poNum") %>' NullDisplayText="--"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_poNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("poNum") %>' Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_amount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("amount") %>' NullDisplayText="--"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_amount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("amount") %>' Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_quantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("quantity") %>' NullDisplayText="--" ReadOnly="True"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Ordered">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ordered" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ordered") %>' NullDisplayText="--"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ordered" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ordered") %>' Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Received">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_received" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("received") %>' NullDisplayText="--"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_received" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("received") %>' Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tech Notes">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 500px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_techNotes" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("techNotes") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("techNotes") %>' NullDisplayText="--"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_techNotes" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("techNotes") %>' Width="380px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

And in my code behind:
    protected void ItemView_OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = ItemView.SelectedRow;
        int itemNum = Convert.ToInt16(ItemView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

        string poNum = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_poNum")).Text;
        string amount = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_amount")).Text;
        string quantity = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_quantity")).Text;
        string ordered = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_ordered")).Text;
        string received = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_received")).Text;
        string techNotes = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_techNotes")).Text;


        string updateQuery = "UPDATE OrderItems SET ";
        bool firstField = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(poNum))
        {
            updateQuery += "purchaseOrderNum = @OrderNum";
            firstField = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(amount))
        {
            if (!firstField) updateQuery += ", ";
            updateQuery += "itemAmt = @Amount";
            firstField = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity))
        {
            if (!firstField) updateQuery += ", ";
            updateQuery += "quantity = @Quantity";
            firstField = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ordered))
        {
            if (!firstField) updateQuery += ", ";
            updateQuery += "dateOrdered = @Ordered";
            firstField = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(received))
        {
            if (!firstField) updateQuery += ", ";
            updateQuery += "dateReceived = @Received";
            firstField = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(techNotes))
        {
            if (!firstField) updateQuery += ", ";
            updateQuery += "techNotes = @TechNotes";
        }

        updateQuery += "WHERE orderItemId = @ID";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForCustomWebApps"]))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(poNum)) 
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNum", poNum);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(amount)) 
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amount);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity)) 
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ordered)) 
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ordered", ordered);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(received)) 
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Received", received);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(techNotes)) 
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechNotes", techNotes);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        ItemView.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }

I have confirmed that the first 2 lines are indeed getting me the correct row (itemNum):
GridViewRow row = ItemView.SelectedRow;
int itemNum = Convert.ToInt16(ItemView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

But then it just breaks. When I run it I get:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error:
Line 116:            int itemNum = Convert.ToInt16(ItemView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
Line 117:
Line 118:            string poNum = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_poNum")).Text;

So that's the first problem.
The second issue is that someone can edit multiple fills in the gridview row, but they don't HAVE to edit them all.  They might enter a PONumber and an amount, but no techNotes or Received Date.  I need an elegant way to check for empty fields for building my update statement. You can see what I've done, which is modeled off something I found on the web. Is there a better way I can do this a loop?
Thank you in advance for any help you can give me. I'm pulling my hair out!

Thanks, I appreciate that, but my issue is how to get the data OUT of the gridview so I can get it into the database.  This reference does not really show me that.

Thanks.  I might have gotten part 1 of my issue working.  Seems like this returns the value I'm looking for:              string poNum = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)ItemView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txt_poNum")).Text;

@Itallmakescents I'm still going to check out those resources you posted though.  I appreciate it.
